# Cannot define a dynamic parameter in a Hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying to set up some Views in Hive that will take a date as a dynamic parameter. In my working  below, I've swapped to using the hiveconf variable  in the Select clause,  so we can see what's going on, but the principle remains the  same

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059040/creating-views-in-hive-with-parameter) and [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201205.mbox/%3CBAY151-W9BC976D584FD172E7D70BC0160@phx.gbl%3E) , I should be  able to include a statement in " ${hiveconf:dateRangeFrom}" in my Create View statement, supply the hiveconf:dateRangeFrom variable at run time for maximum happiness, but  this  is  just not happening - Hive appears to be using whatever value is assigned to the variable when the View is created and hard-coding it into the View definition, not substituting it at runtime as you might expect.

I've got a workaround, whereby I supply a parameter to a sql file that then creates all the views, substituting the desired value in, but this isn't sustainable

All the working is below, so you can see how I came to this conclusion. Any ideas?

---

### 1) Supply a hiveconf value to a simple query

(needs to be a date for the ultimate query)

```
hive -e "Select  ${hiveconf:dateRangeFrom} , unix_timestamp(${hiveconf:dateRangeFrom} , 'yyyy-MM-dd');"  --hiveconf dateRangeFrom='2014-01-01'
```

The date will be returned as suppled, and converted to a unix timestamp (eg "2014-01-01"=1388534400, "2014-09-12"=41047640). The script can be be run repeatedly with results changing accordingly with the  parameter.

### 2) Create a view that returns this data

```
CREATE VIEW get_date AS 
SELECT  ${hiveconf:dateRangeFrom}, unix_timestamp(${hiveconf:dateRangeFrom} , 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

This returns the error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 2:8 cannot recognize input near '$' '{' 'hivevar' in  select clause
```

Presumably because it is trying to do a replacement, but the ${hivevar:dateRangeFrom} variable has not been initialized at this point

According to:
[Creating Views in Hive with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059040/creating-views-in-hive-with-parameter) and 
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201205.mbox/%3CBAY151-W9BC976D584FD172E7D70BC0160@phx.gbl%3E

Then variables can  be used in Hive views, long as quotes are used around them:

```
CREATE VIEW get_date AS 
SELECT  "${hiveconf:dateRangeFrom}", unix_timestamp("${hiveconf:dateRangeFrom}" , 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

This allows the view to be created, so trying to call the view using a parameter:

```
hive -e "Select  * from get_date"  --hiveconf dateRangeFrom='2014-01-01'
```

just returns the variable name:

```
${hiveconf:dateRangeFrom}       NULL
    Time taken: 20.614 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Using single quotes instead:

```
DROP VIEW get_date;
CREATE VIEW get_date AS 
SELECT  '${hiveconf:dateRangeFrom}', unix_timestamp('${hiveconf:dateRangeFrom} ', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Gives the same result, just the variable name.

### 3) Create a view in an interactive session with the variable already set

```
SET hiveconf:dateRangeFrom="2014-02-01";
```

Rebuild the original view, with the variables without quotes

```
DROP VIEW get_date;
CREATE VIEW get_date AS 
SELECT  ${hiveconf:dateRangeFrom}, unix_timestamp(${hiveconf:dateRangeFrom} , 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Then calling "select * from get_date;" from within the session gives the expected result.

As does calling  from the command line, with the same parameter value:

```
hive -e "Select  * from get_date;"  --hiveconf dateRangeFrom='2014-02-01'
```

However, if we call the view with a different parameter, then we still get the original answer:

```
hive -e "Select  * from get_date;"  --hiveconf dateRangeFrom='2014-09-12'

    2014-02-01      1391212800
    Time taken: 24.773 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

If we set the variable inside a new session:

```
SET hiveconf:dateRangeFrom="2014-06-01";
```

or even not  set it all, we still get the  same  result

Looking at the extended view definition, the reason is obvious:

```
hive> describe extended get_date;
OK
_c0                     string
_c1                     bigint

Detailed Table Information      Table(tableName:get_date, dbName:default, owner:
36015to, createTime:1410523149, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescrip
tor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:_c0, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:_c1
, type:bigint, comment:null)], location:null, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapr
ed.SequenceFileInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequen
ceFileOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:nu
ll, serializationLib:null, parameters:{}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameter
s:{}, skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValu
eLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[], parameters:{
transient_lastDdlTime=1410523149}, ***viewOriginalText:SELECT  "2014-02-01", unix_t
imestamp("2014-02-01" , 'yyyy-MM-dd'), viewExpandedText:SELECT  "2014-02-01", un
ix_timestamp("2014-02-01" , 'yyyy-MM-dd')***, tableType:VIRTUAL_VIEW)
Time taken: 0.123 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

The variable substitution took place when the  view was created, and hard-coded that  date into the  definition:

viewOriginalText:SELECT  "2014-02-01", unix_t
    imestamp("2014-02-01" , 'yyyy-MM-dd'), viewExpandedText:SELECT  "2014-02-01", un
    ix_timestamp("2014-02-01" , 'yyyy-MM-dd')

### 4) Switch off variable  subsitution

Hive is clearly putting in the current value of the variable at run-time, so I tried switching  it off and recreating the query:

```
hive> set hive.variable.substitute;
hive.variable.substitute=true
hive> set hive.variable.substitute = false;
hive> set hive.variable.substitute;
hive.variable.substitute=false
```

The Create View statement still fails with the same error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 2:8 cannot recognize input near '$' '{' 'hiveconf' in select clause
```

5) Workaround

If we create a sql file that creates the views, testParam.sql, we can sort of get around the problem:

```
DROP VIEW get_date;
CREATE VIEW get_date AS
SELECT  ${hivevar:dateRangeFrom}, unix_timestamp(${hivevar:dateRangeFrom} , 'yyyy-MM-dd');
SELECT * FROM get_date;
```

Calling that from the command line gives the expected results:

```
hive -f testParam.sql --hiveconf dateRangeFrom='2014-08-01'
2014-08-01      1406847600
Time taken: 20.763 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)


hive -f testParam.sql --hiveconf dateRangeFrom='2014-09-12'
2014-09-12      1410476400
Time taken: 19.74 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

This does work, and will be fine for now, but is hardly ideal for a distributed, multi-user environment. Looking at the view meta-data, we can see that the view is always destroyed and rebuilt with the latest parameters:

```
transient_lastDdlTime=1410525287}, viewOriginalText:SELECT  '2014-09-12', unix_timestamp('2014-09-12' , 'yyyy-MM-dd'), viewExpandedText:SELECT  '2014-09-12', unix_timestamp('2014-09-12' , 'yyyy-MM-dd'), tableType:VIRTUAL_VIEW)
```

So, how to create a view that can be supplied with dynamic parameters at runtime without constantly rebuilding it

Comment: In the try number 1) you can pass variables directly from the shell:
dateRangeFrom=2014-01-01;
hive -e "Select  '$dateRangeFrom', unix_timestamp('$dateRangeFrom' , 'yyyy-MM-dd');"

Comment: I must say the two references that you give are of somewhat dubious quality. It may very well not really be possible.

Comment: probably - it was a while ago now, but I seem to remember I went for the unsustainable version, supplying a variable to a sql file, which then embedded the supplied value into the view ...

Comment: Is anybody aware on whether this is present in newer hive versions? - we seem to have no luck...

Comment: Irene - you probably want to be using Spark/Presto now ...\

Answer (score 0):

How are you defining daterangeFrom? I think daterange from can be  dynamically generated from current_date function by adding and subtracting the days based on your requirement. You can simply use hive functions for that.

Answer (score 0):

I dont if this is what you're looking for!
if you are passing values from a bash script, this should do the job:

```
dateRangeFrom=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
hive -e "Select  '${dateRangeFrom}' , unix_timestamp('${dateRangeFrom}' , 'yyyy-MM-dd');"
```

If you want to set the value in hive script itself you can do something like this

```
hive -e "SET hivevar:dateRangeFrom=2017-11-21;USE mydb; Select  '${dateRangeFrom}' , unix_timestamp('${dateRangeFrom}' , 'yyyy-MM-dd');"
```

If you want to store the same hive query in a HQL file and run it externally, then you need to pass it like this

```
hive -f /abc/user/script.hql --hivevar dateRangeFrom=2017-11-21
```